# I cannot get my verifying email to work, what am i missing?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$TableName = "interns";
if ($errors == 0)
    {
$SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName" . "WHERE email=$email";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
    if ($QueryResult)
        {
            $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);
            if ($Row[0]>0)
                 {
                 echo "<p>The email address enterend (" . htmlentities($email) . ") is already registered.</p>\n";
                 ++$errors;
                 }
        }
    }
```

What have I done wrong here, everything looks good to me. I it is kind of late and maybe I need a fresh pair of eyes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using concatenation to append two string literals?

Comment: try this `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName WHERE email='{$email}'"`

Comment: Also after you solve this make sure to escape $email to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Check for errors. *Always*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space & quotes, change:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName" . "WHERE email=$email";
```

to:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName" . " WHERE email='$email'";
```

or ever more simple (no need for string concatenation):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName WHERE email='$email'";
```

**Addition:**
As j_mcnally suggested below, it would be a good idea to escape the `$email` in order to prevent a possible sql-injection attack

Comment: YOU NEED TO ESCAPE $email! other wise i can inject arbitrary sql.

Comment: @j_mcnally a) and why would you assume that the `$email` field is from user-input ? b) who says that the `$email` wasn't escaped, and c) downvoting an answer means it's not useful!

Comment: The email address enterend (" . htmlentities($email) . ") is already registered.

Comment: @j_mcnally in that case, please ignore c) :)

Comment: im just saying maybe its worth mentioning you should escape email sorry didnt mean to jump down your throat

Comment: you are right we dont have the context to know if $email = $_POST['email'] or an escaped variation.

Comment: @j_mcnally indeed, but it's a pretty good assumption and a good comment. Anyhow, I would `echo` the query and try to run it directly in the db if it looks clean of bugs - to see why no result is returned.

Comment: probably best to have put that comment in the original question not on your answer ;)

Comment: @j_mcnally I added it to the answer ;)

Comment: Yes $email is $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']) and thanks for yall help "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TableName WHERE email='$email'"; worked perfect!!!

Comment: @Kevo89 `stripslashes` is **entirely the wrong function** to be using here (or pretty much anywhere frankly). Look up `mysqli_real_escape_string`.